# Import Bloomberg Excel stock prices into Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to load stock prices in Excel that I downloaded from Bloomberg.

I tried using the data import GUI to see what options were available.
'Column vectors' does not import the name of the stock.
'Matrix' using the spreadsheet name as the name of the matrix. So does 'Cell Array' and 'Dataset'.

How can I get the matrix to use the name of the stock as the matrix name?

Comment: Make sure your first row contains the name of the stock, then import it with 1 header row. Afterwards you can split it up into vectors with that name if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `xlsread`.  You can first read in just the cell that contains the name, and then you can use `eval` to read in the data and assign it to a matrix with the stock name.

Just do `help xlsread`, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! I also ended up adding [~,txt,~] to get the string value.